# Connect multiple devices with USB

Tags: usb, communication, rs485

Consider a setup with 1 "server" device and 4 "client" devices (all are SBCs with Ubuntu installed). I would like to connect the 4 clients to the server, using USB/serial. Ethernet switch is not an option.
The 4 clients should preferably be able to concurrently request the server for data.
The server will not request data the other way around - so it is sort of the opposite of a USB-hub. The devices will be a few meters apart.

**What device would I need to place between the clients and the server to achieve this?**

EDIT:
The dream setup, would be one where the server sees 4 USB devices, e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`, `/dev/ttyUSB1`, `/dev/ttyUSB2`, `/dev/ttyUSB3` and each client just sees `/dev/ttyUSB0`. The device in between controls the data between the ports. Is that possible?

Comment: A USB hub. But you need to have USB integrated into your devices at a hardware and software level.

Comment: @Finbarr You can't connect PCs together with or without a hub, as they are all USB hosts, not USB devices.

Comment: Maybe USB Host ->UART Transmitter -> UART Receiver -> USB Host? This is getting cluttered quickly. Reminds me of funny pictures of 10 adapters inserted into one another.

Comment: USB itself is designed to connect exactly one "client" controller (the SBC) to multiple "servers" (keyboard, mouse, mass storage device, etc.) USB does not support multiple clients/SBCs sharing control of a server/device. There's fundamentally nothing in the USB world that does that. The only thing that comes close is USB-OTG ("-On The Go"), check if your SBC's support that protocol. USB-OTG would let one "client" operate as a "server" role, being controlled from the other end, but it all depends on having supported hardware and supported software.

Comment: @MarkU The clients are Intel NUC's and the server will most likely be as well (or similar). Would USB-OTG work with 4 clients concurrently? Are there other serial protocols that would be appropriate? I found some references to e.g. RS485.

Comment: Why is an Ethernet switch not an option?

Comment: @Justme I'm not suggesting connecting host ports together, many SBCs have USB ports that can act as device ports with just the one server device being the host.

Comment: @Finbarr Can you elaborate, maybe in an answer?

Comment: I'm pretty much saying the same thing as Kuba's answer. The physical connection is easy - your server is the USB host for the hub and the 4 clients need to have their USB ports working in device mode so they can be plugged into the hub ports. But the logical connection doesn't magically happen, you either need to use something like the Gadget/Ethernet software mentioned or write your own drivers to implement whatever protocol you like between them.

Comment: It depends on NUC USB capabilities. Are you using 11th generation with USB4 support?

Comment: @Ale..chenski No, I would prefer a USB-2 compatible solution even.

Comment: What you are describing is connecting each slave to master separately with USB to serial adapters. You don't need any device in between.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I would not mess with serial connections, since software support from those is not as rich as for internet protocols.

RS485 is a physical layer that you won't be using - it's off topic for what you want. You'll be using USB, and “serial” would be totally virtual via CDC - communications device class protocol.

---

The simplest way to connect everything would be using Ethernet, an external 5-port Ethernet switch, and using USB-to-Ethernet dongles.

A cheaper and just as simple way would be to use the Gadget/Ethernet support, where a Linux board can act as a USB Device as opposed to a a USB Host.

> What device would I need to place between the clients and the server to achieve this?

Just a USB hub. The trick is that Linux boards with OTG support can behave either as a USB Host or a USB Device. You'll run the master as a USB Host, connect a hub to it, and connect the slaves as USB Devices.

The clients should be emulating a network interface on their USB OTG port.

For that, you want to use the Linux [Gadget/Ethernet](https://linux-sunxi.org/USB_Gadget/Ethernet) support. Works a treat.

Then the USB connections act exactly like ethernet connections would, from the POV of the operating systems on both ends of the connection.

The “server” machine will see four network interfaces, like if it had a 4-port ethernet card added. The clients will see a single network interface each.

---

You could also use the Gadget support to emulate CDC serial devices instead of network devices, but it'd not be very useful. Network stacks have much more functionality than a simple serial connection does, and there's rich asynchronous support for network connections, with a multitude of programming environments and libraries. So exposing the devices as network nodes as opposed to serial nodes will make your life much easier.

I've done it in the past when Gadget/Ethernet was young, and even then it worked surprisingly well. Cheap, too, since you can supply both power and a network connection using just USB cables and a USB hub you can buy anywhere, even at some gas stations.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is buying 8 USB to serial adapters. Connect 4 to host and one per controlled device. Connect each device to host. Done.

Depending on which exact USB to serial adapter you end up with (TTL, RS232, RS485) the detailed procedure how to wire them together will vary, but maybe four null-modem cables will do for RS232 adapters.